# Is there a equivalent of allow-insecure-localhost flag of Google Chrome in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, firefox, websocket

I want to connect "wss" (SSL-ed websocket) with insecure (self signed) cerfiticate.
But it is raise a error.
This error caused by default firefox setting that it seems like does not allow connecting to self-signed ssl as well as chrome.

In Chrome, this behaivior is able to change by `allow-insecure-localhost` flag in chrome://flags.

Is there a equivalent flag in Firefox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Navigate to

> about:config

and look at:

> network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS

but it won't be for localhost only so be carefull :D

Comment: so I mentioned also

Comment: It will do for now until Mozilla introduces a feature. Thanks alot.

Comment: @mirkobrankovic It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't think this is the right thing to do. Instead, you can manually ACCEPT the risk by visiting the page. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53011185