# CORS request across different ports did not succeed on Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: firefox, cors, lighttpd, self-signed

I'm making CORS requests from `https://169.254.128.2:8443` to APIs served on `https://169.254.128.2:8444` by lighttpd server. Lighttpd has CORS enabled with the following response headers but the OPTIONS request does not go through on Firefox.

```
setenv.add-response-header = (
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*" (tried https://169.254.128.2:8443 too),
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "accept, origin, x-requested-with, content-type, x-transmission-session-id, x-ida-auth-token, content-disposition",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" => "X-Transmission-Session-Id",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"
    )
```

I get the error: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT. I'd like to know if there is a way to communicate with 8444 other than explicitly accepting the certificate for 8444. I already accept the certificate for 8443 when I first access the url `https://169.254.128.2:8443` and 8444 and 8443 use the same certificates.
The requests go through fine on both Chrome and Safari without accepting certificates.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700837

You must enable the certificate on each port individually.

Open the url in Firefox and accept the certificates for
`https://169.254.128.2:8443` and `https://169.254.128.2:8444`

Comment: OMG! Thank you Jesus.

Comment: Thank you so much, after so many years, this just delivered me from some pain after about an hour of debugging.