# Vue CLI 3.5.5 standard install showing webpack websocket errors

Tags: vue.js, webpack

[image]I recently upgraded my VUE CLI to 3.5.5

After running the standard install, I noticed CORS and websocket errors being thrown in the browser  ...Connection closed before receiving a handshake response. The errors are thrown in both Firefox and Chrome.

I am guessing this has something to do with the webpack devserver and CORS but its a guess because I know nearly nothing about webpack.

I added a vue.config.js and tried various configs for the webpack devServer but none have worked.

Can anyone illuminate this issue? - it must be very common. Thanks

Comment: can you paste the error stack trace?

Comment: new to Vue so Ive no idea where to collect stack traces. All I can see is console errors

Comment: As far I know cors request did not success means something network problem may be. If it really something to do with cors browser will suggest to add some headers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Comment: can you check this link once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831652/cors-request-did-not-succeed-on-firefox-but-works-on-chrome

Answer (score 0):

So the solution i found was to create a vue.config.js file at the root level of the project and use this webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
 devServer: {
 host: "0.0.0.0",
 public: "0.0.0.0:8080",
 disableHostCheck: true,
 proxy: {
   "/app": {
     target: "http://localhost:8081",
     changeOrigin: true,
     ws: true
     }
   }
 }
};
```